# Making color from color name in QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, expression, data-defined-override

I have a layer containing `color` field storing color names as text like `red`, `green`. The layer is read-only.

```
id  color 
1   green
2   red
3   blue
4   green
```

I would like to define -using data-defined override- the color of features using those color names. I reviewed the color functions in Expression window, but I couldn't find a suitable one.

[image]

Is there a way to define a color using color names?

Comment: Doesn't it work if you set your Symbol Color property to be by expression, expression simply being `color`

Comment: Use a "Single Symbol" in the symbology and set the field name in the expression for the full colour. Works for me.

Comment: @Kasper Believe me, I didn't think it was that simple. Can you add it as an answer, please?

Comment: @kadir Hard to believe, but I have to !

Comment: BTW is there opportunity to use local color names? Like 'rouge' or 'Rot' or 'წითელი' instead of 'red'?

Comment: @RainForest I guess it only understands English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tried to follow idea of @Kasper and @Spacedman.

I was amazed, but it really is that simple.

1. Open layer properties panel
2. Select style as "Single symbol"
3. Sel fill color as data defined.
4. Choose the field containing text strings of feature color. It's "code" in my example or "color" in question.
   That's all.

[image]